# Receiving errors on empty GET variable

Tags: php

Im building an application that shows off various types of records for my team as a whole. to start this is the menu (some with **$_GET** information on them)

The html menu that brings up this page looks like this:

```
<li><a href="web.php">WEB department</a>
        <ul>
    <li><a href="web.php?tstname=Mike">Mike</a></li>
        <li><a href="web.php?tstname=Deidre">Deidre</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The webpage that pulls the web data, the important part is this below

```
    $pullWebTeamData = "SELECT * FROM tlm_accounts WHERE type_of_account = 'WEB' ;";
    $pullWebTeamDataDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $pullWebTeamData) or die ("could not pull WEB team data" . mysqli_error($c2d));

then further down the page i output the data i want. For example

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullWebTeamDataDoIt)){
    //do stuff here - - - **this part never changes** 

    }
```

Then this pulls all the records for the web team as a whole. In this fashion i thought "hmm it'd be even more useful if I can display the records for each of the teams members individually.

Obviously, im not going to make an individual page for ALL the members of the company so i thought of re-purposing  this page so that if a GET variable equals a persons name, that certain data is shown.

here is the code

```
$tstname= $_GET['tstname'];


    if($tstname == "Mike"){
        $pullWebTeamData = "SELECT * FROM tlm_accounts WHERE type_of_account = 'WEB' ;";
        $pullWebTeamDataDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $pullWebTeamData) or die ("could not pull WEB team data" . mysqli_error($c2d));
    } elseif ($tstname == "Deidre"){
        $pullWebTeamData = "SELECT * FROM tlm_accounts WHERE type_of_account = 'WEB' ;";
        $pullWebTeamDataDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $pullWebTeamData) or die ("could not pull WEB team data" . mysqli_error($c2d));
    } else {
        $pullWebTeamData = "SELECT * FROM tlm_accounts WHERE type_of_account = 'WEB' ;";
        $pullWebTeamDataDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $pullWebTeamData) or die ("could not pull WEB team data" . mysqli_error($c2d));

    }
```

Now although it pulls the data I want(named get link or normal web link), the problem is that on page load, if the person clicks the regular web page link that doesn't have $_GET information attached. It throws an error because at that point the "$_GET" in:

```
$tstname= $_GET['tstname'];
```

doesnt exist. How can i make it so that if the "$_GET" doesnt exist. to just ignore it?
Feels like i should know this....lol anyways,

i tried things like

```
if(!empty($testname)){ do stuff }
```

or `if($testname) //since this equals to true if not empty...`

etc but to no avail. Hope I was clear. any tips/help etc i humbly appreciate.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: why the down vote? im new......

Comment: Being new has nothing to do with it. Questions/answers are down voted not people. (I'm not one of the down voters btw).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Well if you check, i said i tried the if and checking for empties, if you look below(before it got edited), people better than me made the same mistake. Even then, the answer that got up voted, isnt entirely complete. When put with my code(shown above) it still shows an error because "if(isset)" still doesnt fix the code after it which relies on the get var. A "else { $nameForPersWhiteBoard = "";} had to be added to take out the error. Anyways...thanks all who helped.

Answer (score 3):

use `isset`

```
if(isset($_GET['tstname'])) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I had originally tried this and i still got the error which is why i came here...eventually, i tried this again and i had to add a " } else { $nameForPersWhiteBoard = ""; } to your "isset" and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator for setting the variable.

```
$tstname= !empty($_GET['tstname'])? $_GET['tstname']: ' ';
```

or

```
 $tstname= isset($_GET['tstname'])? $_GET['tstname']: ' ';
```

Comment: @Adrian Why? That depends on what exactly you want to check for. `!empty` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @AdrianCrepaz can u give a fully explanation why should !empty not suits here?

Comment: @Adrian **Wrong!** Actually *read* the page you link to: *"No warning is generated if the variable does not exist."* Also: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @AdrianCrepaz _"Full-time Web Developer from the UK."_

Comment: It usually depends how you create the condition.Does my condition created will generate index error?

Answer (score 0):

$tstname= isset($_GET['tstname'])?$_GET['tstname']:'';